# Discord JS: How do I move all member inside an array into a channel?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to move all member within an array into a channel. The array `memberIDs` contains the IDs from the Member I want to move. The variable `gameChannel` contains the channel id as a string. My Code looks like this:

```
memberIDs.forEach(element => message.guild.member(element).voice.setChannel(gameChannel));
```

Answer (score 0):

To move a member you must first get its data (GuildMember) and then move it.

Discord.js^12

```js
var gameChannel = 'CHANNEL_ID';
var memberIDs = ['SOME_ID_HERE', 'OTHER_ID_HERE', '...'];

// For each element of the 'MemberIDs'
memberIDs.forEach(id => {
  // Assuming 'guild' is the Server Guild
  var member = guild.member.cache.get(id); // Get member
  if(member){
    // Move
    member.voice.setChannel(gameChannel, 'reason (this can be empty)')
    .then(e => console.log('User moved successfully'))
    .catch(e => console.log('An error occurred while trying to move the user'));
  }
});
```